# How to display number in money format

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to display Number with comma in following format in C#.

Ex: 12345678
I want to display this number as 1,23,45,678

Can any one give answer for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello, what is your rule for formatting : 3 last then by packs of 2 ?

Comment: If you wanted a comma every 3 numbers I would use `money.ToString("C");`

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? The part about format strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, this is an Indian style of formatting the currency.

```
Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-IN")));
```

where intValue is the number you want to format.

For the same input in your question, you should get exactly "1,23,45,678".

Comment: It is giving like this 1,23,45,67,890.0, After dot how to display 2 zeros. Example 1,23,45,67,890.00  Thanks

Comment: Try giving N2 instead of N1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int number = 12345678 ;
Convert.ToDecimal(number).ToString("#,##0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

```
Double number = 12345678;
String output = number.ToString("C2");
```

Check out the **[Currency Formatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString)**.

> The "C" (or currency) format specifier converts a number to a string
>   that represents a currency amount. The precision specifier indicates
>   the desired number of decimal places in the result string. If the
>   precision specifier is omitted, the default precision is defined by
>   the NumberFormatInfo.CurrencyDecimalDigits property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom Format  The Currency  Format Specifier `C` or `c` using `ToString()`

From MSDN: Custom Format `c` or `C`

> Result: A currency value.
>
> Supported by: All numeric types.
>
> Precision specifier: Number of decimal digits.
>
> Default precision specifier: Defined by System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.

Try This:

```
int myVal= 12345678;
string finalVal= myVal.ToString("C");
Console.WriteLine(finalVal);
```

Try This: if you dont want precision.

```
int myVal= 12345678;
string finalVal= myVal.ToString("C0");
Console.WriteLine(finalVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = 123456789; 
string Result = number.ToString("#,##0");
```

Try this.
Hope it helps

```
using System.Globalization;


NumberFormatInfo info = new NumberFormatInfo();
        info.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3, 2 };
        int number = 12345678;
        string Result = number.ToString("#,#", info);
```

here you Go...

Comment: Not what is asked.. Output for this is  : 12,345,678, question is about  1,23,45,678

Comment: Yes Jurion,3 last then by packs of 2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
string.Format("{0:C}", 12345678)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use cultureinfo to show currency with your number

decimal dec = 123.00M;
string uk = dec.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"); // uk holds "£123.00"
string us = dec.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-US"); // us holds "$123.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, a very dirty solution, but could not figure if there is a format for this.

So I take last 3, then by packs of two :

```
            int number = 212345678;
            string semiRes = number.ToString();
            var lastThree = semiRes.Substring(semiRes.Length - 3, 3);
            List<string> resulatArray = new List<string>();
            resulatArray.Add(lastThree);
            semiRes = semiRes.Substring(0, semiRes.Length - 3);
            for (int i = 2; i <= semiRes.Length + 2; i = i + 2)
            {
                var start = semiRes.Length - i;
                var len = 2;
                if (start < 0)
                {
                    len = 2 + start;
                    start = 0;
                }
                var nextTwo = semiRes.Substring(start, len);
                resulatArray.Insert(0, nextTwo);
            }
            var result = string.Join(",", resulatArray);
            if (result.StartsWith(","))
            {
                result = result.Substring(1);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you..following function is giving same result.Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString("N1", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("hi-IN")));